# AngularJS: how to initiate a ng-click on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

We have a widget in ServiceNow where we have buttons that show pre-configured filters.  The buttons work great onClick, but we would like the first button to be clicked and the first filter to be applied on load.  Is there a way to initiate this on load?  We tried using ng-init, but we couldn't get that to work.

```html
<p><strong>Filters:</strong></p>
<button ng-if="options.show_preconfigured_filters=='true'"
        class="btn btn-outline-primary pull-left m-r-sm m-b-sm"
        ng-repeat="filters in data.preconfigured_filters | orderBy : 'order' track by $index"
        ng-click="c.applyFilter(filters);">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter m-r-sm"></i>{
   {filters.title}}
</button>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

```js
c.applyFilter = function(filter) {
    $scope.data.filter = filter.filter;
    c.appendQuery($scope.data.filter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to compute the ordered list in the controller:

```
var orderedList = $filter('orderBy')($scope.data.preconfigured_filters, 'order');

c.applyFilter(orderedList[0]);
```

This executes the same function that a user invokes by clicking the first item.

Comment: Hi @georgeawg, I just tried that but get a console error that says cannot read property '0' of undefined.  When I wrapped the first line around an if($scope.datapreconfigured_filters), I get an error saying cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.